# How to select a specific row that has been sorted among other rows in an ascending manner?

Tags: r, subset

Under "heart failure", I am attempting to do the title's activity. I am passing the number 3 to the argument and then I am sorting the data followed by using this number to select the row, but having no success.

```
best("AK","pneumonia", 3)

best <- function(state, outcome, num) {
  #read file function

  #Reads the csv file
  dataTable  <- read.csv("outcome.csv", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

  #Passes the state argument to the choice variable
  choice <- state
  #selects all rows which match the state that was selected
  stateOfChoice <- dataTable[dataTable$State == "AK",]





  #Makes sure that only three of outcomes found in the csv file are selected
  if(outcome != "heart failure" && outcome != "heart attack" && outcome != "pneumonia"){
    print("wrong condition, try again")
    main()
  }

  #using the selected rows from above, return the minimum value of rate from heart attack and then use this selected row to find the hospital name
  else if (outcome == "heart attack"){



    heart_attack <- stateOfChoice[which.min(stateOfChoice$Hospital.30.Day.Death..Mortality..Rates.from.Heart.Attack),]
    heart_attack
    hospital <- heart_attack$Hospital.Name
    hospital
    return(hospital)
  }

  #Similar as above, but instead with heart failure
  else if (outcome == "heart failure"){

    ?order

    orderState <- stateOfChoice[order(as.integer(stateOfChoice$Hospital.30.Day.Death..Mortality..Rates.from.Heart.Failure),decreasing = FALSE),]
    orderState
    #orderStateNum <- orderState$Hospital.30.Day.Death..Mortality..Rates.from.Heart.Failure[[num]]
    orderStateNum <- subset(orderState,Hospital.30.Day.Death..Mortality..Rates.from.Heart.Failure == num)
    orderStateNum  
    ##heart_failure <- stateOfChoice[which.min(stateOfChoice$Hospital.30.Day.Death..Mortality..Rates.from.Heart.Failure),]
    hospital <- heart_failure$Hospital.Name
    return(hospital)
  }

  #Similar as above, but instead with pneumonia
  else if (outcome == "pneumonia"){


    pneumonia <- stateOfChoice[which.min(stateOfChoice$Hospital.30.Day.Death..Mortality..Rates.from.Pneumonia),]
    pneumonia
    hospital <- pneumonia$Hospital.Name
    return(hospital)
  }

}
```

Here is the data:

[Pls click to get the data](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_sKokV1rcnAzjJsbRWqLTd2GL4GqAfHq)

Comment: Are you wanting the top X rows, or to return row X (if it exists)?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you were asking to return X number of rows, or row number X. Here are both solutions.

### Top X Rows

You can use `head(dt, num)` to get the top X rows from a data frame. Since you have already sorted it should work to give you your top 3.

```r
orderStateNum <- head(orderState, num)
hospital <- orderStateNum$Hospital.Name
return(hospital)
```

### Only row X

This is one you just feed it the row number you want.

```r
  else if (outcome == "heart failure"){

    orderState <- stateOfChoice[order(
      as.integer(stateOfChoice$Hospital.30.Day.Death..Mortality..Rates.from.Heart.Failure
                 ),decreasing = FALSE),]
    orderStateNum <- orderState[num,]
    hospital <- orderStateNum$Hospital.Name
    return(hospital)
  }
```

Comment: Hi John, the second is in line on what I am looking for. Are you missing  a "$Hospital.30.Day.Death..Mortality..Rates.from.Heart.Failure" somewhere? I don't see how the row from this particular variable (column) gets selected.

Comment: Your code already sorted it by "$Hospital.30.Day.Death..Mortality..Rates.from.Heart.Failure". I will update my response to include a bigger chunk, maybe I missed something.